# can anyone explain what @ _* mean in this code snippet?

Tags: scala

```
def swapElementsOfArray(array: Array[Int]) = 
    array match {
        case Array(x, y, z @ _*) => Array(y, x) ++ z
        case _ => array
}
```

I don't get how @ _* is used here. can anyone help to explain that? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The operator `_*` makes reference to a sequence of elements, in your case, it'd be the "tail" of the array.

The operator `@` allows you to bind a matched pattern to a variable, in your case "z"

So with `z @ _*` you are assigning to Z the rest of the array you are not using but you need to refer to it later.

```
val a= Array(2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2)
def swapElementsOfArray(array: Array[Int]) =
  array match {
    case Array(x, y, z @ _*) => Array(y, x) ++ z
    case _ => array
  }

swapElementsOfArray(a).toString
```

`res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 2`

z would be "3,5,3,2" you don't need it for use but you need the reference.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific example `_*` means "the rest of the array".

The `z @` part is standard pattern match syntax for binding a variable name to a pattern

Please note that the `_*` operator is a general operator that applies to any vararg parameter, and it's sometimes referred to as the "splat operator".

You can read about it in the specification: https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#repeated-parameters

Here's the relevant sentence:

> The only exception to this rule is if the last argument is marked to be a sequence argument via a `_*` type annotation. If `m` above is applied to arguments `(e1,…,en,e′: _*)`, then the type of `m` in that application is taken to be `(p1:T1,…,pn:Tn,ps:scala.Seq[S])`

This applies to both matching and passing varargs. For example, the splat operator can be used to pass a sequence where a vararg is expected.

Example:

```
val s = Seq(1, 2, 3)
val a1 = Array(s) // does not compile
val a2 = Array(s: _*) // compiles, s is passed as vararg

a2 match {
  case Array(s @ _*) => s // s now contains all the elements of a2
}

a2 match {
  case Array(head, tail @ _*) => head // tail contains all the elements except the first
  case _ => ??? // empty list!
}
```